# Is there a Panel Listener in Java?

Tags: java, swing, events, jframe, jpanel

I have a custom JFrame Class and I want to add a listener that does the following:

If the content pane of my Frame is Panel1, the Frame should be resizable with `setResizable(true)`, and if the content pane is another Panel, the Frame shouldn't be resizable.

Does anybody know how to code such a Listener? What Listener Class does it implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a listener for this. Somewhere you are setting the content pane in your frame. At the same place you should also call `setResizable(true/false)`.

Your code should look something like this then:

```
if (contentType == type1) {
   this.contentPane = new Panel1();
   setResizable(true)
} else {
   this.contentPane = new AnotherPanel();
   setResizable(false)
}
```